# Disk benchmark exceeds theoretical maximum

Tags: benchmarking

My laptop has 2 X 256GB SSD in RAID 0 each one is rated at: 
540/450MB/s for read/write.

On Crystal disk mark using 8 threads and 8 queues and 4GB test size it got 2811MB/S for Read but I am not sure how this is possible. If you want evidence please look at the picture I have attached.

Could you explain what queues and threads are and how this insanely fast speed is possible?

Could you explain how many queues and threads would give you the fastest write speed?

[image]

Comment: Have you used in other tools to benchmark the drive?  Why have you only performed a single benchmark with the tool what about the other 3?  Your results are normal by the way.

Comment: I have used other tools and I have run this one several times and when using a 4GB test size 8 threads and 8 queus the results ranged from 3100-2700 MB/S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caching.
Either at the OS layer or at the disk controller.

Sequential I/O is highly optimizable, particularly as systems have a relatively large amount of free RAM available for opportunistic caching.

Comment: +1 for caching. I once wrote a naive file transfer test program to test throughput and the first run on a 2gb file was a sane number, the second run was always instantaneous.

Comment: Especially these days where it's not unusual to work on 64-bit machines with 8 GB RAM or more.  Windows 7+ will happily use all available RAM to cache the hell out of disk I/O.  It's pretty cool, unless the power goes out that is.